# Will O or S accept an electron more easily?

Tags: periodic-trends

O has more electronegativity than S but S has more Electron Gain enthalpy than O. How do we decide, which one pulls the electron more easily? In other words, Electron gain enthalpy dominates or electronegativity ?

Comment: The two quantities are completely different. The electron gain enthalpy is "the energy released when one mole of electron are added to gaseous atoms of an element". The electronegativity is the tendency of an atom to attract a bonding pair of electrons.

Comment: @user34388 Exactly! But which one of them decides the fate of the pulled electron?

Comment: To me it is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean with pulling and the fate of the electron?

Comment: That should depend on the situation. For example, effects such as inductive effects in a molecule should be based more on EN than EA. You should be using EA if you're drawing a Born-Haber diagram.

Comment: @aventurin what i mean is, which element will pull the electron more easily? * this is a book question *

Comment: @AaryanDewan Then your book is unclear.